# Max iteration of Tensorflow object API with resnet faster r-cnn

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, resnet

I am training Oxford dataset using tutorial with ResNet101 Faster R-CNN.

I am running the training on my local machine with 1 GPU not using Google Cloud.

My question is may I know what will be the max iteration?

My step is already over than 13,000,000 and did not stop yet.

The original faster r-cnn could define max iteration size here
https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn/blob/master/tools/train_faster_rcnn_alt_opt.py#L80

, but I am not sure about TensorFlow object detection API.

I did not change any parameter except for input_path and fine_tune_checkpoint (which I am using COCO pre-trained data with ResNet).

I thought that the max iteration will be in config file
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/samples/configs/faster_rcnn_resnet101_pets.config#L100, but it seems it only define learning rate after certain step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/running_locally.md) `By default, the training job will run indefinitely until the user kills it`. So, run the training and evaluation jobs simultaneously and kill the processes(early stopping based on the validation accuracy saturation.

Note: from Jonathan comment, you can also add the number of steps explicitly [num_steps](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/samples/configs/faster_rcnn_resnet101_pets.config#L116)

Comment: Thanks! I missed it.

Comment: Also note that you can explicitly add, for example, a `num_steps: 2000000` line to the TrainConfig part of your pipeline, which would force the training binary to terminate after two million iterations.

Comment: Got it. https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/samples/configs/faster_rcnn_resnet101_pets.config#L116